# Offscreen Rendering in OpenGL or Directx

Tags: opengl, 3d, server, 2d, directx

I want to be able to render complex 2D and 3D images using hardware acceleration on a server with no user context or logged in user. The best thing I could do so far is [Mesa3D](http://www.mesa3d.org/), but because it is pure software 3D rendering it is slow and does not take advantage of the video hardware acceleration. Could be Windows or Linux. Most of my work I have done so far in Windows.

Any suggestions on how to do this with OpenGL or DirectX?

Comment: "[Mesa] is pure software 3D rendering it is slow and does not take advantage of the video hardware acceleration"...[wat](http://www.mesa3d.org/systems.html)

Comment: I guess we are not using the hardware drivers with mesa3d because of the windos session 0 user context issues...I will gather more info...

Answer (score 2):

For Linux, EGL + [`MESA_platform_gbm`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/egl/extensions/MESA/EGL_MESA_platform_gbm.txt) should let you get a completely headless/X11-less OpenGL context.

The spec helpfully includes an example program demoing usage:

```
// This example program creates an EGL surface from a GBM surface.
//
// If the macro EGL_MESA_platform_gbm is defined, then the program
// creates the surfaces using the methods defined in this specification.
// Otherwise, it uses the methods defined by the EGL 1.4 specification.
//
// Compile with `cc -std=c99 example.c -lgbm -lEGL`.

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#include <EGL/egl.h>
#include <gbm.h>

struct my_display {
    struct gbm_device *gbm;
    EGLDisplay egl;
};

struct my_config {
    struct my_display dpy;
    EGLConfig egl;
};

struct my_window {
    struct my_config config;
    struct gbm_surface *gbm;
    EGLSurface egl;
};

static void
check_extensions(void)
{
#ifdef EGL_MESA_platform_gbm
    const char *client_extensions = eglQueryString(EGL_NO_DISPLAY, EGL_EXTENSIONS);

    if (!client_extensions) {
        // EGL_EXT_client_extensions is unsupported.
        abort();
    }
    if (!strstr(client_extensions, "EGL_MESA_platform_gbm")) {
        abort();
    }
#endif
}

static struct my_display
get_display(void)
{
    struct my_display dpy;

    int fd = open("/dev/dri/card0", O_RDWR | FD_CLOEXEC);
    if (fd < 0) {
        abort();
    }

    dpy.gbm = gbm_create_device(fd);
    if (!dpy.gbm) {
        abort();
    }


#ifdef EGL_MESA_platform_gbm
    dpy.egl = eglGetPlatformDisplayEXT(EGL_PLATFORM_GBM_MESA, dpy.gbm, NULL);
#else
    dpy.egl = eglGetDisplay(dpy.gbm);
#endif

    if (dpy.egl == EGL_NO_DISPLAY) {
        abort();
    }

    EGLint major, minor;
    if (!eglInitialize(dpy.egl, &major, &minor)) {
        abort();
    }

    return dpy;
}

static struct my_config
get_config(struct my_display dpy)
{
    struct my_config config = {
        .dpy = dpy,
    };

    EGLint egl_config_attribs[] = {
        EGL_BUFFER_SIZE,        32,
        EGL_DEPTH_SIZE,         EGL_DONT_CARE,
        EGL_STENCIL_SIZE,       EGL_DONT_CARE,
        EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE,    EGL_OPENGL_ES2_BIT,
        EGL_SURFACE_TYPE,       EGL_WINDOW_BIT,
        EGL_NONE,
    };

    EGLint num_configs;
    if (!eglGetConfigs(dpy.egl, NULL, 0, &num_configs)) {
        abort();
    }

    EGLConfig *configs = malloc(num_configs * sizeof(EGLConfig));
    if (!eglChooseConfig(dpy.egl, egl_config_attribs,
                         configs, num_configs, &num_configs)) {
        abort();
    }
    if (num_configs == 0) {
        abort();
    }

    // Find a config whose native visual ID is the desired GBM format.
    for (int i = 0; i < num_configs; ++i) {
        EGLint gbm_format;

        if (!eglGetConfigAttrib(dpy.egl, configs[i],
                                EGL_NATIVE_VISUAL_ID, &gbm_format)) {
            abort();
        }

        if (gbm_format == GBM_FORMAT_XRGB8888) {
            config.egl = configs[i];
            free(configs);
            return config;
        }
    }

    // Failed to find a config with matching GBM format.
    abort();
}

static struct my_window
get_window(struct my_config config)
{
    struct my_window window = {
        .config = config,
    };

    window.gbm = gbm_surface_create(config.dpy.gbm,
                                    256, 256,
                                    GBM_FORMAT_XRGB8888,
                                    GBM_BO_USE_RENDERING);
    if (!window.gbm) {
        abort();
    }

#ifdef EGL_MESA_platform_gbm
    window.egl = eglCreatePlatformWindowSurfaceEXT(config.dpy.egl,
                                                   config.egl,
                                                   window.gbm,
                                                   NULL);
#else
    window.egl = eglCreateWindowSurface(config.dpy.egl,
                                        config.egl,
                                        window.gbm,
                                        NULL);
#endif

    if (window.egl == EGL_NO_SURFACE) {
        abort();
    }

    return window;
}

int
main(void)
{
    check_extensions();

    struct my_display dpy = get_display();
    struct my_config config = get_config(dpy);
    struct my_window window = get_window(config);

    return 0;
}
```

You can use `eglBindAPI( EGL_OPENGL_API )` to use OpenGL instead of OpenGL ES.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows, you can use Direct3D 11 "headless" (i.e. without an output window/swap chain and running in session 0) with a hardware device on Windows 8 / Server 2012 or later. Prior to that, people had some luck using WARP (a software renderer) and/or the NULL device.

See [Direct3D 11.1 Features](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh404562.aspx#use_direct3d_in_session_0_processes)